# Good method name for 2 different actions

Tags: oop, design-patterns, naming-conventions

I have a method `Send` and a method `Store`. I need a wrapper for both but I can't find a good name for it.

What can you do in this situation to avoid calling the method `SendAndStoreEmail` ? 
Is there any trick for naming different actions like this in a facade class ?

Comment: how about processEmail()....

Comment: @mr_lewjam: *process* can easily mean: *reading*, *formatting*, *interpreting*, *redirecting*... *anything*

Answer (score 1):

I'd be happy with... `Send()`! Here's why:

`MailService.Send()` calls `MailSender.Send()` *and* `MailStorage.Store()`. `MailService.Send()` handles the process of sending e-mails. From implementation perspective this process consists of physically sending an e-mail and storing it. But from the <del>user</del> perspective of other developer using your code it just sends e-mails. Storing them is technical, irrelevant (?) detail.

Comment: I think the code should be clear from a developer perspective not from a user persective ?!?

Comment: @danip: sure, by *user* I mean other developer *using* your code, clarified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what information you want to expose to the outside world.

If you want to tell explicitly what your methods do, then by all means use explanatory names such as `StoreAndSendEmail()` (you'd want to store it first, then send it, so please respect the order of the actions in your names).

If you don't want/need to be as clear, you can use any naming convention you want, for example you may use a name such as `ProcessMessage()` if that fits your specific circumstances.

Or just call it `SendItToBigBird()` and see if you get reactions ;-)

Good luck!